# Determining whether a subset is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis

How would one determine whether the following subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ is opened or closed.

$$X=\left\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2},\ (x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2+2y^2=0\right\}.$$

Let me remind you that a subset is open if $\forall x \in X\ \exists \epsilon $ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \in X$.

Comment: LOL, it's $\infty$!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, notice that in general one does not exclude the other, and there are sets that are neither open nor closed.

That being said, let
$$f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^2-2x^2+2y^2.$$
Then $X = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, and therefore it is closed. As $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, the only sets that are at the same time open and closed are the empty set and the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself. As $(0,0)\in X$, $X$ is not empty, and since $(1,1)\notin X$, $X$ is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, $X$ is closed and not open.